# Heredoc without quotes not expanding parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create and use variables inside heredoc like this,

```
#!bin/bash
sudo su - postgres <<EOF
IP="XYZ"
echo "$IP"
EOF
```

This doesn't work right and I get a blank line as echo.
But if I use quotes around `EOF` like this,

```
#!bin/bash
sudo su - postgres <<"EOF"
IP="XYZ"
echo "$IP"
EOF
```

It works. Can someone please explain this? According to what I read in `man` the behaviour should be opposite.

Comment: What is your output for each command? In the first the variable will be expanded, in the second it won't. Also the variable is never set as it just seen as a string.

Comment: Note that the problem is actually the converse of the problem description: the here doc without quotes _is_ expanding parameters!

Comment: as I mentioned, the only output is of `echo` which gives a blank line in the first one and the correct output i.e `XYZ` in the second one.

Comment: @123 you should have left that answer as is. It was helpful too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell evaluates the unquoted here document and performs variable interpolation before passing it to the command (in your case, `sudo`). Because `IP` is not a defined variable in the parent shell, it gets expanded to an empty string.

With quotes, you prevent variable interpolation by the parent shell, and so the shell run by `sudo` sees and expands the variable.

Comment: Oh cool, I moved `IP` outside of the heredoc without quotes and tried to access it , it worked as intended. Thanks I get it now.

Comment: Also to add, @wolfsgang, if you want to selectively expand some variables from parent shell & some are defined in heredoc (`IP` in this case), you can escape the `$` sign in `$IP` with `\ ` & keep the `EOF` word unquoted.

Comment: @anishsane , thanks for the tip,it's pretty helpful. Definitely will keep that in mind.